# How to find the amount of people are following one specific user on Scratch, and how do I add it to my project?

Tags: mit-scratch

So, I am working on a project that includes having a live follow count on it, so how do I add it? I also do not know how I can acsess the api base from inside the project.

I have wondered and I have not came up with a viable solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

That is not possible, but it might be upcoming in a later Scratch version. For now that is beyond the limits of scratch. You can make a view counter that updates a cloud variable by one every time a project is loaded, but users could autoclick and cheat the system so that it would provide incorrect values.